# Django REST Framework: raise error when extra fields are present on POST

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

When you're writing a serializer, it is trivial to specify which fields will be included (via `Meta`'s `fields`), setting read/write permissions on them and validating them. However, I was wondering if there is an easy way to specify that *only* the fields that are included are to be expected and any extra keys passed in should raise an error.

E.g. say, I have a serializer

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.ModelA
        fields = ('name', 'number')
```

Supposed further that I don't have any validations.

And I'm `POST`ing this payload to create a new instance

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "number": 5
}
```

Everything is fine.

But suppose my API has changed and now I'm also storing a new field, `title`, but forget to update my serializer. Clients will be sending payloads that look like

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "number": 5,
    "title": "Mr"
}
```

However the serializer will simply ignore the extra key, not raising an exception.

So, my question is: is there any way to make a serializer *only* expect fields specified in `fields` or -- if it's not a `ModelSerializer` -- fields, specified as members, and raise an error if it's not the case?

Comment: You can simple override `restore_object` or `restore_fields`, call your parent and do your check on the provided `attrs`

Comment: Looking at this question some time later, I would probably have recommended using `jsonschema`, and simply error if the payload fails schema validation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a rest\_framework Serializer disallow superfluous fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352960/how-to-make-a-rest-framework-serializer-disallow-superfluous-fields)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Came across this question and found that using [object level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) is a bit easier. This entails simply defining a validate method:

```py
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            unknown_keys = set(self.initial_data.keys()) - set(self.fields.keys())
            if unknown_keys:
                raise ValidationError("Got unknown fields: {}".format(unknown_keys))
        return data
```

Comment: `raise ValidationError({unknown_keys.pop(): 'Unexpected field'})`  is also an option.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as of djangorestframework==3.9.4

Comment: @SimonKohlmeyer I'm not sure of your exact issue, but I encountered a bug with the above check. So I updated the answer to include the check `if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):`, because sometimes `.validate` is called before `self.initial_data` has been set.

Comment: It helped alot. Thanks for the answer. @m

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by overriding the `is_valid()` method of the serializer. Here, we will check if any of the key in the `payload` is not a serializer field using `filter()` and `lambda` functions.

If `filter()` returns some fields which are not in the serializer fields, then we raise a `ValidationError`. Else, we call the `super()` method and it will then perform the normal serializer validation.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MySerializer(..):

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            payload_keys = self.initial_data.keys() # all the payload keys
            serializer_fields = self.fields.keys() # all the serializer fields
            extra_fields = filter(lambda key: key not in serializer_fields , payload_keys) 
            if extra_fields:
                raise ValidationError('Extra fields %s in payload'%extra_fields)
        return super(MySerializer, self).is_valid(raise_exception)
```

Comment: Won't `if extra_fields:` always be True because it 'is' a filter (whether empty or not)?