# How to make a rest_framework Serializer disallow superfluous fields?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I've noticed that the Serializer isn't really strict when it comes to rejecting input with unknown fields:

```
In [1]: from rest_framework import serializers

In [2]: class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   ...:     foo = serializers.CharField()
   ...:     

In [3]: s = TestSerializer(data=dict(foo='foo', bar='bar'))

In [4]: s.is_valid()
Out[4]: True
```

Is there a way to configure the `Serializer` to return a validation error about `bar` being unexpected in this situation?

Answer (score 14):

This definitely works:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        unknown =  set(self.initial_data) - set(self.fields)
        if unknown:
            raise ValidationError("Unknown field(s): {}".format(", ".join(unknown)))
        return attrs
```

**Nested and list serializers**

This will not work if you use a such a serializer as a field in another serializer. In which case, the child serializer won't have access to initial data and you will get an exception.

Same with a `ListSerializer` (or `many=True`) as the list serializer's child serializer won't get the individual `initial_data` items (there is a github [ticket](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5345) for this).

In that case the slightly less clean solution which works all both cases is:

```
from rest_framework.fields import empty
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField()

    def run_validation(self, data=empty):
        if data is not empty:
            unknown = set(data) - set(self.fields)
            if unknown:
                errors = ["Unknown field: {}".format(f) for f in unknown]
                raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    api_settings.NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY: errors,
                })

        return super(TestSerializer, self).run_validation(data)
```

Comment: Pro tip: `set(some_dict)` works just as well as `set(some_dict.keys())`

Answer (score 3):

With django REST framework v. 3.3.0 it will be:

```
class _FieldSetValidatingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
    super().is_valid(False)

    fields_keys = set(self.fields.keys())
    input_keys = set(self.initial_data.keys())

    additional_fields = input_keys - fields_keys

    if bool(additional_fields):
      self._errors['fields'] = ['Additional fields not allowed: {}.'.format(list(additional_fields))]

    if self._errors and raise_exception:
      raise ValidationError(self.errors)

    return not bool(self._errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

`s.data` does not contain `bar` so what is the use case where it matters?

After looking at the docs I didn't see a native solution. You could override `.validate()` to do a check and raise `ValidationErrors` that way. I didn't test this with when `partial=True` so you will want to check that if you're using it.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        has_unknown_fields = set(attrs.keys()) - set(self.fields.keys())

        if has_unknown_fields:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("dont send extra fields")

        return attrs
```

Comment: I like the approach but `validate` is called after `restore_fields` so it doesn't see the extra input entries, I'd need to plug in somewhere else. My use case is a regular REST API - I think it should raise an error if unexpected POST parameters are there, so that the user would be notified if he e.g. mistypes an optional param.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. I was testing by adding `attrs['bar'] = 'blah'` inside the `.validate()` method.

Comment: Another possible solution although I don't think it's clean. You have access to `self.context['request']._request.POST` in `.validate()`. You would have to filter out certain keys like `csrfmiddleware` and `_method` but you would be left with what the user actually supplied and could compare that against `self.fields.keys()`.