# DRF serializer check undefined field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I used `drf` and also used `serializer` to check user input.

Here is my serializer.py

```
class BoardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    body = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

And use it like this.

```
serializer = BoardSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
     ....
```

It seems that doesn't check undefined field.

For example, If I request with `{'user_id':1, 'body': 'abc', 'akak': 1}`,

`is_valid()` do not catch field 'akak' and just pass the data.

Is there any function to validate if fields is defined in serializer or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a rest\_framework Serializer disallow superfluous fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352960/how-to-make-a-rest-framework-serializer-disallow-superfluous-fields)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the validation method like this:

```
class BoardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    body = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        unknown =  set(self.initial_data) - set(self.fields)
        if unknown:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Unknown field(s): {}".format(", ".join(unknown)))
        return attrs
```

Here, it will check if there is any extra fields passing through the serializer and compare with existing fields. If it exists, then it will throw error(or make `is_valid() == false`). For more information, you can check this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36205600/2696165).

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Because **akak** is not define in **BoardSerializer**

You need to add akak in serializer.

You can add custom field akak in seralizer

to catach akak, try this

```
request.data.get('akak')
```

Comment: I mean that, I want to validate if user input has undefined field in serializer.

Comment: @Hide does your undefined fields are fixed