# Updation in patch request

Tags: python, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I have made a model as Meme in Django having 3 fields like `name`,`url`, `caption` but I want that name field will not get update during PATCH request and throw an error.

I have made a class for error and written this code in my patch function :

```py
class MyError(Exception): 
  
    def __init__(self, value): 
        self.value = value

    def patch(self, request, id):
        try:
            meme = Meme.objects.get(id=id)
        except Meme.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        
        serializer = MemeSerializer(meme, data=request.data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            try:
                key = 'name'
                if key in serializer.data:
                    v = serializer.data['name']
                    raise MyError(v)
            except MyError:
                return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
                   
            return Response(serializer.data)
        
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But still, the name field gets update when I try to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the field is updated is because you call `serializer.save()` before raising the error. You can simply move the validation to be right after the is_valid you called.

However, what you should do (to solve it DRFly) is set up the validation in the serializer (to cause the "is_valid()" to raise a ValidationError.)

Try following this answer:
[Django REST Framework: raise error when extra fields are present on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178266/django-rest-framework-raise-error-when-extra-fields-are-present-on-post)

(You can specify only a patch request by passing context to the serializer and accessing it using self context).
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

Another option (if you want to ignore the "name" field instead of raising an error) would be setting it as a create only field. This article covers the different ways pretty well - http://blog.qax.io/write-once-fields-with-django-rest-framework/

Good luck!

Comment: I have added the code of-  Use a second serializer from [link](http://blog.qax.io/write-once-fields-with-django-rest-framework/) but the name field is still getting update but this time only from PUT request and PATCH request is not updating any fields along with name

Comment: Could you Aladd your serializer codes to the question?

Comment: It's working now but could please tell me how to add an error if some try to update the name field

Comment: In the is_valid method (or even in the view) you can raise a ValidationError("Custom error message").
DRF knows how to handle these errors and returns a 400 error with a custom message to the user.